# How to add a canvas element in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, anime.js

I want to add [this](https://codepen.io/alexzaworski/pen/mEZvrG) canvas to my react app, the problem is that JSX does not support script tags, so how can I use external javascript like animejs engine in the component, also I need to add the javascript for the canvas itself which does things like `document.getElementById("c");`. to get a better idea about what I am trying to do, please visit:

https://codepen.io/alexzaworski/pen/mEZvrG